# Add Array Column to Multidimensional Array Using array_merge in foreach Loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, var-dump

I'm trying to add another column of data to each row in a foreach loop. It's purpose is to remember the element of data importeded from XML processed to an multidimensional array.  It's stuck as a scalar though the var_dumps looks fine.

```
<?php 
$KEY = 0;
foreach ($eventsArray as $keyMe){
  $thisKey['KEY'][0] = strval($KEY);
  $keyedArray = array_merge($keyMe, $thisKey);
$KEY++;
}

// Prep for multisort
foreach ($keyedArray as $key => $value){
  $date[$key] = $value['DATE'];
  $title[$key] = $value['TITLE'];
  $link[$key] = $value['LINK'];
  $slide[$key] = $value['SLIDE'];
  $location[$key] = $value['LOCATION'];
  $time[$key]= $value['TIME'];
  $KEY[$key] = $value['KEY']; // Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array
}

/* var_dump(
array(7) { 
  ["DATE"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2012-12-18" } 
  ["TITLE"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Event Title" } 
  ["LINK"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "aLinkLocation.htm" } 
  ["SLIDE"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "16" } 
  ["LOCATION"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "Location of Event" } 
  ["TIME"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "8am" } 
  ["KEY"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "23" } 
} 
*/
```

Comment: You are doing $KEY[$key], when you defined $KEY as INT ($KEY = 0;). You're treating an INT as an array, therefore you get a warning. I'm not sure what you're doing, but what if you do $KEY = array(); before the second foreach?

Comment: $KEY is the value I'm trying to add to the array.  I tried array($KEY=0) but the problem persists.

Comment: Try doing $KEY = array(); before the second foreach, so you won't get that warning, and you'll be able to do $KEY[$key] = $value['KEY'];. Also, I noticed you overwrite $keyedArray in the first foreach, I don't know if that's intentional.

Comment: $KEY = array(); turns off the warning.  Can't retreive the $keyedArray[KEY][0] value though after multisort.  The overwrite is intentional, was that bad, maybe my problem?

Comment: Hmm what about change all your $value['DATE|TITLE|LINK|etc'] to $value[0]? so it's $KEY[$key] = $value[0];

Comment: It was that darned overwrite. After changing $keyedArray in first foreach to $keyedArray[$KEY] and it works fine.  THANKS!!!